# What are the steps to modify a table from 3NF to BCNF along with its dependency using SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have three tables, T1, T2 and T3. T1 has the three-dimensional primary key of (T1K1, T1K2, T1K3). T3 has a one-dimensional primary key of (T3K1). Between T1 and T3 there is an n:m relation represented by T2. T2 has a one-dimensional primary key of (T2K1). T2 references T1(T1K1, T1K2, T1K3) via (T2T1K1, T2T1K2, T2T1K3) and references T3(T3K1) via T2(T2T3K1). I would like to modify T1 to be in BCNF, so I would like to add a single-column primary key to it and modify (T1K1, T1K2, T1K3) to be no primary key. Since T2 has a primary key to T1, I need to drop the foreign key constraint from there first. T1, T2, T3 already have records.

My question is: What is the fastest way with SSMS to achieve what I want?

My idea is as follows:

1. Drop the foreign key constraint from T2 which references T1.
2. Drop the primary key constraint from T1.
3. Add an identity integer ID column to T1 and make it the primary key
4. Add a column to T2 and make it foreign key to T1.

I am afraid of the following: When at step 3, the script might fail because of existent data. If that is the case, then I will have to create temporary tables, export the data, remove everything from both tables, modify the schema and reimport. I have real data in these tables, hence my question.

Comment: The process normalize a relation to BCNF has to do with functional dependencies. It doesn't have to do with adding "an identity integer ID column"--normalization *never* introduces new attributes. What's the *real* problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall', There was a 3d primary key containing a textual column making everything slow, so I made a 1d numeric primary key instead.

Comment: Is there a `not null unique` constraint on {T1K1, T1K2, T1K3}?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall', it was a primary key. After the modification I have added a unique index on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer appears to be the following:

- Remove the `foreign key` from T2
- Remove the `primary key` from T1
- Add a `column` to T1 as `primary key` and identity
- Add a `column` to T2 with the same type as the new `column` described in the previous step
- Make the new `column` of T2 `foreign key` and index it